# Error when referencing schemaComponents

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I have two separate schemas that use the same components. I've tried to create schemaComponents so that I can update both schemas in one location however I get an error `ReferenceError: SchemaComponents is not defined` when I use it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I was under the impression this was allowed.

Path: `SchemaComponents.js`

```
SchemaComponents = {
  schools: {
    type: [String],
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      options: [
        {label: "School One", value: 'SchoolOne'},
        {label: "School Two", value: 'SchoolTwo'},
        {label: "School Three", value: 'SchoolThree'},
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

Path: `StudentSchema.js`

```
StudentSchema = new Mongo.Collection("studentSchema");

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.StudentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    school: SchemaComponents.schools,
});

StudentSchema.attachSchema(Schemas.StudentSchema);
```

Path: `TeacherSchema.js`

```
TeacherSchema = new Mongo.Collection("teacherSchema");

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.TeacherSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    school: SchemaComponents.schools,
});

TeacherSchema.attachSchema(Schemas.TeacherSchema);
```

Comment: Why not use ES-2015 imports in order to control load order?

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around this new way of using meteor. How does the load order affect how schema design above? noob question.